# TASK: Better Code: Copy workbooks - Multiple sheets, identical ranges but data values that differworksheet to worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, coding-efficiency

I have two workbooks consisting of multiple worksheets, each of which contains data that differ from worksheet to worksheet, in the range `(B7:P100)`.  I need to copy the data from the range of each worksheet to the corresponding worksheet and range in the other workbook.

The following code accomplishes this: however, it seems to me there is probably a more elegant way to accomplish the same result.  I am slowly becoming proficient in the brute strength and ignorance method of VBA programming but would like to  better understand VBA.  I have tried to work with a 3D array of ranges; but it is evident I do not fully understand complicated arrays.

The following code is abbreviated to save space.  (There are 18 worksheets that must be copied)

Can you suggest a more elegant or more efficient approach (or approaches) to accomplishing the task?  I would appreciate your comments.

```
Workbooks("Nutrition  Update.xlsm").Worksheets("Breakfast").Range("B7:P100").Value = _
Workbooks("Nutrition.xlsm").Worksheets("Breakfast").Range("B7:P100").Value

Workbooks("Nutrition Update.xlsm").Worksheets("Lunch").Range("B7:P100").Value = _
Workbooks("Nutrition.xlsm").Worksheets("Lunch").Range("B7:P100").Value

Workbooks("Nutrition Update.xlsm").Worksheets("Dinner").Range("B7:P100").Value = _
Workbooks("Nutrition.xlsm").Worksheets("Dinner").Range("B7:P100").Value
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub CopyStuff
Dim wbSource as Workbook
Dim wbTarget as Workbook
set wbsource = workbooks("Nutrition  Update.xlsm")
set wbtarget = workbooks("Nutrition.xlsm")
dim ws as worksheet 
for each ws in wbsource.worksheets  'loop through every sheet
  wbtarget(ws.name).range("B7:P100") = ws.range("b7:p100").value 'copy to same name in target
next ws
end sub
```